# Placeholder i18next translation not working

Tags: json, node.js, internationalization, ejs, i18next

I have created a registration form. I am using i18next server side.

This is my server-side configuration:

```
var i18n = require('i18next');
i18n.init({
saveMissing: true,
debug: true
});

app.use(i18n.handle);
```

The following is my locale json"

```
{
"app": {
  "lblalreadyhaveanaccount": "¿Ya tienes una cuenta?",
  "lblsignin": "Ingresar",
  "lblhelp": "Ayuda",
  "lblletscreateyouraccount": "Vamos a crear su cuenta",
  "lblname": "Nombre",
  "phfirstname": "Nombre de pila",
  ....
 }
```

I am using ejs as my template engine. This the following code:

```
...
<form ng-submit="validateForm()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <!-- Name -->
                    <label><%= t('app.lblname') %></label>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="fname" type="text" class="form-control"
                                   placeholder=<%= t('app.phfirstname') %>>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="lname" type="text" class="form-control"
                                   placeholder=<%= t('app.phlastname') %>>
                        </div>
                    </div>
  ....
```

My Question is that the label having multiword string are rendered properly, however the placeholder shows only the first word from the string in locale json.

Here is what inspect element shows:

```
<input id="fname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" de="" pila="">
```

I am unable to find a solution to this problem. Kindly help me out.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How does your "lblletscreateyouraccount" key look?  Maybe there is some weird encoding that you can't see.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. The problem remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the browser is trying to make sense of the words in the input tags. To help it along, try adding double quotes around your placeholder text, like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="fname" type="text" class="form-control"
               placeholder="<%= t('app.phfirstname') %>"
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="lname" type="text" class="form-control"
               placeholder="<%= t('app.phlastname') %>"
    </div>
</div>
```